# how to close Persistent conn in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, oracle, laravel

i am using laravel and oracle to develop application where i am using Persistent connection of laravel oci8 
using below code i set app/config/database.php

```
 'oracle' => array(
            'driver'   => 'oracle',
            'tns'      => env('DB_TNS', '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)))'),
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'     => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'Test_DB'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'admin'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'admin'),
            'charset'  => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
            'prefix'   => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'options' => [
                \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
            ]

        )
```

Problem is that i want to recreate database connection when new user login to the system.How will i close conn of laravel.please help me on that

Answer (score 3):

If you need to close connection;

```
\DB::disconnect();
```

If you need to only reconnect;

```
\DB::reconnect();
```

But if you need to change connection;

```
\DB::purge('oracle');
\Config::set('database.default', 'oracle_the_new');
\DB::connection('oracle_the_new');
```

Note: If you do not change database.default laravel will always reconnect default connection. Or you can change Model's connection;

```
$user  = new User();
$user->setConnection('oracle_the_new');
$user1 = $user->find(1);
```

Comment: will \DB::disconnect(); close the persistent connection

Comment: Yes but when your script does a database query laravel will reconnect.